# Natural deseasters and how to interpret the verses about Allah's punishment?

Tags: quran, tafseer

In sura hud Ayat 117, it is mentioned by Allah SWT:

> And your Lord would not have destroyed the cities unjustly while their people were reformers.

Why there are earthquake happened like in Muzaffarabad and Balakot in 2005, where people are mostly religious and reformers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this verse (surah 11, verse 117) God speaks about the past in the context of some cities that were destroyed. He says if those people were righteous, then he would not have destroyed the cities unjustly.

> وَمَا كَانَ رَبُّكَ لِيُهْلِكَ الْقُرَىٰ بِظُلْمٍ وَأَهْلُهَا
>   مُصْلِحُونَ

The conclusions you are making are problematic and your question cannot be answered. The contexts of that time and the context of today are very different.

- It is not correct to conclude that whenever a city has no reformers, that city would be destroyed.
- It is not correct to conclude that if a city has reformers, that city would not be destroyed.

Comment: I reckon it's also not correct to conclude that the 2005 earthquake, terrible though it was, holds a candle to the city-destroying-wrath-of-god-everybody-dies destruction of old.